# What is the difference between msg.sender, from and spender in ERC20 tokens?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

**my contract**

```
contract Token{
    string public name = "Dhruv";
    string public symbol = "DhruvToken";
    uint256 public decimals = 18;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    mapping(address => uint) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

    constructor() public{
        totalSupply = 1000000 * (10 ** decimals);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }

    //events
    event Transfer(address from, address to, uint256 value);
    event Approve(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 indexed value);

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success){
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    //internal function can be accessed only within the smart contract
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value)  internal{
        require(_to != address(0));
        balanceOf[_from] = balanceOf[_from] - _value;
        balanceOf[_to] = balanceOf[_to] + _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    }

    // approve the tokens
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success){
        require(_spender != address(0));
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approve(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;

    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value)  public returns (bool success){
        // require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] =  allowance[_from][msg.sender] - _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**functions called**

```
token.transferFrom(deployer, receiver, amount, { from: exchange })
token.approve(exchange, amount, { from: deployer });
token.allowance(deployer, exchange);
```

**my doubts**

- token.allowance is allowing exchange i.e. spender to spend a particular amount of tokens but in the transferFrom we are resetting the allowance of msg.sender by spender to spend a particular amount of tokens, that creates a confusion why there is a role switch
- why we call functions using curly braces  and why we dont directly pass out the values in the functions
- please clarify the role of msg.sender in the transaction why exchange directly dont call the transaction and why there is a need of intermediary

Please answer my doubt i had researched a lot but this doubt hadn't cleared yet

Comment: Please answer i am really stuck here, please suggest if i need to edit my question to make it more clear  i am really stuck here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry I think I won't be able to answer all your questions.
Without much more context, as far as I understand, the main purpose of this contract is to let someone allow another person to send tokens on his behalf to a potential third party.

A valid scenario for me would be :

-"A" deploys the contract.

-"B" calls the token.approve function (so B is the msg.sender here) to allow C to spend a value in its behalf. (let's say for this exemple : 10)

```
allowance[B][C] = 10;
```

-"C" calls the token.transferFrom function to send some B's token to D.(let's says 6. Note that now C is the msg.sender)

```
allowance[B][C] =  allowance[B][C] - 6; (10-6 --> C still can send 4 tokens from now on)
```

Now with these three function calls :

> token.transferFrom(deployer, receiver, amount, { from: exchange })

```
allowance[deployer][exchange] =  allowance[deployer][exchange] - _value;
```

> token.approve(exchange, amount, { from: deployer });

```
allowance[deployer][exhange] = _value;
```

> token.allowance(deployer, exchange);

You just retrieve the updated amount of tokens that can be sent.
The order of these function calls doesn't quite make sense to me as I would expect the approve function to be called first.

Regarding the curly braces, I am not acquinted to this syntax. I am more used to something like

```
token.transferFrom(deployer, receiver, amount).send( { from: exchange } )
```

in javascript. Anyway it is just a way to use key-value pairs as an argument of a function.  Probably the first arguments (out of the curly braces) are for the  Token member function, and the one between curly braces, for the an equivalent of the send function I gave as an exemple above.

Hope that this will help you.